# How can I replace string between two characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I replace a string between two given characters in javascript?

```
var myString = '(text) other text';
```

I thought of something like this, using regex but I don't think it's the right syntax.

```
myString = myString.replace('(.*)', 'replace');
```

My expected results is myString = 'replace other text';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a text replacement where the exact text is searched for. You can use a regex for searching a pattern

```
myString = myString.replace(/\(.*\)/, 'replace');
```

Comment: This won't work with multiple instances of the search term: try it using the string `'(text) other text, and (more text)'`

Answer (score 2):

You can match just bracketed text and replace that:

```
myString.replace(/\(.*\)/g, 'replace');
```

or, if you only ever want to match `(text)`, use

```
myString.replace('(text)', 'replace');
```

Your original wasn't working because you used a string instead of a regex; you were literally looking for the substring `"(.*)"` within your string.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of choice is fine with one instance of `(text)`. It won't work with something like `'(text) other text, and (more text)'`. In that case, use:

```
var str = '(text) other text, and (more text)';
var strCleaned = str.replace(/\(.*?[^\)]\)/g, '');
//=> strCleaned value: 'other text, and '
```